# Уведомление с сайта о скачивании файла в телеграм

Tags: html

Всем привет!

Имеется сайт, созданный без использования движков.

На сайте имеется один файл для скачивания. Хотелось бы сделать уведомления в Телеграмм о его скачивании пользователем.

Подскажите, как можно это реализовать?

За ранее благодарен.

Comment: Собственно с чем трудности? Вы не можете отследить скачивание файла или не можете создать бота?

Comment: В том что не знаю как все реализовать, задумка заключается в том чтобы человек прошел регистрацию на сайте после чего в обязательном порядке скачал файл и об этом мне должно придти уведомление в телеграмм что файл скачен пользователем.

Comment: `в обязательном порядке скачал файл` - ну не с ножом же у горла вы будете его заставлять скачивать) Суть в том, что вам нужно отслеживать скачивание файла (на сервере это сделать проще) и затем апи бота. Начните делать и когда у вас появятся **конкретные** вопросы по реализации, задавайте их тут